# How can I get my numbers from a character separately in R?

Tags: r

[image]

```
newdata <- "1311 1381 1382 1311 1222 1221 2819 2869 2911 2879 5171 5172 6719 1311 1381 1382 2899 2833 2879 2869 2819 1311 1311 1381 1382 2911 5541 6719 2911 2865 2821 2822 2819 5171 5172 5541 1311"

class(newdata)
[1] character
```

As is shown in the picture, I have a dataset, one of the data is `newdata`, it is a `character`.

I would like to know how to get the numbers in the string separately.
Ultimately, I would like to get a list such as

```
[1311,1381,1382,1311,1222,1221,....]
```

Comment: Do you need `as.numeric`?

Comment: or is it character-numeric mixed data? Please add sample data(non-image data)

Comment: I add a sample data1

Comment: See `help(scan)`

Answer (score 3):

How does this work for you:

```
 library(tidyverse)

newdata <- "1311 1381 1382 1311 1222 1221 2819 2869 2911 2879 5171 5172 6719 1311 1381 1382 2899 2833 2879 2869 2819 1311 1311 1381 1382 2911 5541 6719 2911 2865 2821 2822 2819 5171 5172 5541 1311"

    str_split(newdata, " ") %>% map(., as.numeric)   # for list output
    str_split(newdata, " ") %>% map(., as.numeric) %>% bind_cols() # for df/tibble
    str_split(newdata, " ") %>% map(., as.numeric) %>% bind_cols() %>% .[["V1"]] #for vector
```

Comment: You are very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the suggestions in the comments resolved your issue, but another possibility is to use `strsplit`.

Let's consider a `character` vector

```
newdata <- c(
    "1311 1381 1382 1311 1222 1221", 
    "2819 2869 2911 2879 5171 5172 6719 1311 1381 1382 2899 2833")
```

Then we can do

```
lst <- lapply(newdata, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))))
lst
#[[1]]
#[1] 1311 1381 1382 1311 1222 1221
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 2819 2869 2911 2879 5171 5172 6719 1311 1381 1382 2899 2833
```

The result is a `list` of `numeric` vectors

```
str(lst)
#List of 2
# $ : num [1:6] 1311 1381 1382 1311 1222 ...
# $ : num [1:12] 2819 2869 2911 2879 5171 ...
```